# Using JQuery Autocomplete using array and drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a script that will use JQuery's autocomplete text box to display county data from an array that has been filtered by state. State is a drop down list. So for example: if a user has selected "Illinois" for the state, based on the begging letters they type into the text box, autocompklete would give them the closest county name. I was successfully able to filter the array by state and then load the array with the correct data but I am having problems trying to load the array into autocomplete. Here is the code segment. Thanks much for your help:

```
    <body >
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function findCounties(State)
      {
var County = new Object();

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (xmlhttp != null)
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET","US_Counties.csv",false); // the false makes this synchronous!
    xmlhttp.send();
    var text = xmlhttp.responseText;

    // text contains the ENTIRE CONTENTS of the text file
    // you *could* just write those contents directly to the HTML output:


    // but you might want to process that one line at a time.  if so:
    var lines = text.split("\n");

    var cntCounty = 0;
        for (var n=0; n<lines.length; n++)
        {
            if(lines[n].indexOf(State) > 0){
                var line = lines[n];
                var populate = line.split(',');


                County[cntCounty] = populate[1];
                cntCounty++;

            }//IF
        }//for
    $(function() {
            var Counties = [{
         a_state: []
        };
        for(var i in County) {

        var item = County[i];

            Counties.a_state.push({ 
            "label" : item.County
        "value" : item.County`enter code here`
        });
    ];

  j$("#counties").autocomplete({
    source: Counties 
  }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label ++ "</a>").appendTo (ul);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this javascript code:

```
var stateList, countyList;

$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: "US_counties.csv", // list of counties
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                window.alert(textStatus);
            },
            success: function (text, textStatus, xhr) {
                var s1 = $('#s1')[0]; // the select box
                stateList = [];
                // each line has one county on it
                $.each(text.split("\n"), function (ix, elt) {
                    var items = elt.split(','),
                        stateName = items[0],
                        countyName = items[3], a;
                    if (typeof stateList[stateName] == 'undefined') {
                        a = [];
                        a.push(countyName);
                        stateList[stateName] = a;
                        // add state to the select box
                        s1.options[s1.options.length] = new Option(stateName, stateName);
                    }
                    else {
                        stateList[stateName].push(countyName);
                    }
                });

                // set the change event handler for the dropdown
                $('#s1').bind('change', function() {
                    countyList = stateList[this.value];
                    $("#t1") // the text box
                        .autocomplete({ source: countyList })
                        .val('');
                });

                // trigger a 'fake' change, to set up the autocomplete
                $('#s1').trigger('change');
            }});
});
```

Explanation: `stateList` is a list of lists.  The inner index of that list is the state name, or in my case, the state abbreviation (AL, AK, AZ, etc).  Each item in the `stateList` is a list of strings, each one is the name of a county in that state.

What the code does:

- registers a function for the document ready event.
- in that function, get the CSV for the county list via ajax.
- in the success callback for that ajax call, parse the result.  For each new state, add an item to the `stateList`, and add that state to the dropdown.  Add the county to the list of counties for that state. Also bind a change event handler to the dropdown.
- in the change handler, apply an autocomplete to the "county name" textbox.  The source is the list of county names for the state selected in the dropdown.

---

**EDIT** - FYI, I got the list of counties from [this list](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/gazetteer/files/Gaz_counties_national.txt), and merely replaced tabs with commas. Replacing tabs with commas was not necessary but it makes it easier for me to browse the list in a text editor. If you don't replace tabs with commas then you'll need to modify the call to `elt.split()` to split on the tab character.

Comment: Thanks much Cheeso I will verify and  try this.

Comment: @Chesso:  Unrotunately I was notified that I need to access the list remotely using a query to a SalesForce data Object